# Softlayer ReST API to get all billing items for an account

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have been using this endpoint to get all billing items for an existing account.

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getAllBillingItems.json

However, it stop working and I'm getting an error below. Other API endpoint still works except this one.

> {"error":"Internal Error","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}

Answer (score 0):

Well, it likely because now you have a lot billing items, when the response of your request is very big you are going to get a similar error.

The way to head off the error is using resultLimits, you can see more information here:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/using-result-limits-softlayer-api
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/REST

For example using a simple Restful request to get the billing items you can use this:

```
GET https://username:apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getAllBillingItems.json?resultLimit=0,200
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you Nelson, this works. Wish the error would be more descriptive here.